# How can I issue a POST request that contains a basic authentication header, and a JSON body?

Tags: c++, json, rest, cpprest-sdk

I am trying to use the CPPRESTSDK (a.k.a. Casablanca) to POST data to a RESTful server. To do this, I create a request, and assign a header:

```
// create request, and add header information
web::http::http_request req(methods::POST);
req.headers().add(header_names::authorization, authStr); // authStr is base64 representation of username & password
req.headers().add(header_names::content_type, http::details::mime_types::application_json);
```

Next, I make a web::json::value object that contains all the key-value pairs:

```
web::json::value obj = json::value::object();
obj[U("Key1")] = web::json::value::string(U("Val1")];
obj[U("Key2")] = web::json::value::string(U("Val2")];
obj[U("Key3")] = web::json::value::string(U("Val3")];
```

I then store this object in the request's body by calling:

```
req.set_body(obj);
```

Finally, I send the request to the server using an http_client:

```
// create http client
web::http::client::http_client client(addr); // addr is wstring

return client.request(req).then([](http_response response) {
    return response;
});
```

The problem is that this doesn't do anything. If I place a breakpoint on this line, I get information about "400 Bad Request." I would assume that the request's body is somehow malformed, but it could also be that I am missing some information in the header. This error does not happen when I issue a GET request on the same URL, so it is definitely a problem with POSTs specifically. What do you think?

Here is a working example:

```
// create a new channel
pplx::task<web::http::http_response> postChannel(http_client client, std::wstring authStr, std::wstring cDesc, std::wstring cName, std::string cDiagCap, int cNormFloat, int cWriteDuty,
int cWriteMeth, std::string cItemPersist, std::wstring cItemPersistDat) {
// create request
http_request req(methods::POST);
req.headers().add(header_names::authorization, authStr);

std::wstring url = L"/config/v1/project/channels";
req.set_request_uri(url);

json::value obj = json::value::object();
obj[U("common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION")] = json::value::string(cDesc);
obj[U("common.ALLTYPES_NAME")] = json::value::string(cName);
obj[U("servermain.CHANNEL_DIAGNOSTICS_CAPTURE")] = json::value(cDiagCap == "true" || cDiagCap == "t");
obj[U("servermain.CHANNEL_NON_NORMALIZED_FLOATING_POINT_HANDLING")] = json::value(cNormFloat);
obj[U("servermain.CHANNEL_WRITE_OPTIMIZATIONS_DUTY_CYCLE")] = json::value(cWriteDuty);
obj[U("servermain.CHANNEL_WRITE_OPTIMIZATIONS_METHOD")] = json::value(cWriteMeth);
obj[U("servermain.MULTIPLE_TYPES_DEVICE_DRIVER")] = json::value::string(U("Simulator")); // right now, Simulator channels are the only option
obj[U("simulator.CHANNEL_ITEM_PERSISTENCE")] = json::value(cItemPersist == "true" || cItemPersist == "t");
obj[U("simulator.CHANNEL_ITEM_PERSISTENCE_DATA_FILE")] = json::value::string(cItemPersistDat);

req.set_body(obj);

return client.request(req).then([](http_response response) {
    return response;
});
```

}

Comment: If a `GET` works on the same URL, then clearly the server does not allow a `POST` to the same URL. Are you sure you are posting to the right URL? Also, if `authStr` is *just* the base64 data by itself, then it is incomplete. It needs to start with `"Basic "` followed by the base64.

Comment: You're right. There was a typo in the name of a property in my JSON object.

Comment: Could you please post your working example here JTM? Thanks